# How to insert hyphen between letters instead of line-break?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

What I want to do is so that when word riches the end of the line to divide word into two words and insert hyphen before line-break. It's similar to `<wbr>` tag but it doesn't inserts anything.
Examples:

```
Java-  <--- I want to insert this hyphen before line-break
Script
```

or

```
Ja- <---- Same here
vaScript
```

Is there anyway of doing it? I don't mind using `php`, `javaScript` but `jQuery` would preferable and if I can achieve it using `CSS` or `HTML` that would be great.
Thnx in advance!

Comment: Do you want the hyphens to automatically move when the user resizes the browser? (Also, hyphenation as per your second example makes for hard-to-read copy - why do you want to do that?)

Comment: I think it would be very difficult to do this with javascript as a general case, Adding hyphens may change the layout and possibly move already inserted hyphens to the wrong place. Inserted hyphens will need to able to be identified (to allow for re-hyphenation on window resize or other layout change) so perhaps they should be in a SPAN element with an appropriate class (e.g. insertedHyphen). As noted in one answer, you need a [set of hyphenation rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen), you can't simply add characters until the line is almost full, insert a hyphen and continue.

Comment: Can the soft hyphen `&shy;` help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it client-side, you will need a hyphenation plugin. Reason being, there needs to be a dictionary of hyphenation rules to follow, and that's something that's not simply included in the browser. [update: although, that statement is partially false already! Chris's link shows limited (very limited, but still... promising!) support.]

Here's one jQuery plugin I found: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/hyphenation and I know I've used one in a project before (may have been this one even). It will of course insert the hyphen into the node's contents, but the content doesn't need to have it included, the hyphenation is calculated by the function after DOM ready.

Whether or not the rules are extensive enough to break up words outside of the 'norm' is another question.

Side note: JavaScript is a proper noun, which should be excluded from hyphenation. I imagine that was just an example off the top of your head, though. ;-)

Comment: ye, 'JavaScript' was from my head! I totally forgot that jQuery plugin can almost everything what you want. Thnx for plugin!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is some [limited browser support for CSS hyphenation](http://blog.fontdeck.com/post/9037028497/hyphens). Does that work for you?

Comment: Thnx! I will probably use it in the near future, but for right now I go for jQuery plugin as @Greg suggested

Answer (score 0):

This function should solve your problem. 
It insert **Soft Hyphen | $shy;** into *"long"* words.

---

- **pText** = Your string
- **pMax** = Every X Char in a word insert a Soft Hyphen;

---

```
function hyphen(pText, pMax){
        var t = pText.split(" ");
        for(i=0; i<t.length; i++){
                if(t[i].length<pMax){
                        var w = t[i]
                        var re = new RegExp("(.{"+pMax+"})","g");
                        if(w.length<pMax+3){
                                var pos = t[i].length - 3;
                                re = new RegExp("(.{"+ pos +"})","g");
                        }
                        t[i] = w.replace(re,"$1"+&shy;);
                }
        }
        return t.join(" ");
}
```